# Leetcode - how to optimize my solution using sliding window approach for maximum number of vowels in a substring of k length?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sliding-window

I am doing leetcode [1456](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-number-of-vowels-in-a-substring-of-given-length/)

I came up with a working solution but got "Time limit exceeded" for one of the [tests](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/638105347/testcase/). I used the sliding window approach and I believe my solution is O(n) (or am I wrong?).

```
var maxVowels = function(s, k) {
   let left = 0;
   let right = 0;
   let maxVowels = 0;
   let curVowels = 0;
   let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];

   while (right < s.length) {
       let subStringLength = right - left + 1;
       if (vowels.includes(s[right])) curVowels++;
       
       if (subStringLength === k) {
           maxVowels = Math.max(maxVowels, curVowels);
           if (maxVowels === k) return maxVowels;
           curVowels = 0;
           left++;
           right = left - 1;
       }           
       right++;
   }
   return maxVowels;
};
```

I tried to see if it was because the `vowels.includes(s[right])` method was somehow a really slow method but based on what I read that is not the case, especially since my array is only of length 5.

How can I optimize my solution such that it passes the test?

Comment: `curVowels = 0;` and `right = left - 1;` looks wrong. What is this supposed to do?

Comment: @Bergi, the `curVowels = 0` resets the current count of vowels in my substring to zero. `right = left - 1` basically makes the right pointer move to the left of the left pointer so that when `right++` next executes, both the left and right pointers start at the same index. I noticed that my approach is slightly different because when I look at other people's solutions, they just increment the left and right border by 1 instead of my approach which essentially 'resets' the count and arrows.

Comment: Yes, I see what it's doing, but it's not clear *why* you're doing that. It's not a sliding window, it's a window that is getting opened and closed and opened and closed repeatedly. This causes `O(n * k)` complexity - notice you're only incrementing `left` every time `substringLength` reaches `k` (which might be big!)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi! Thats actually a great analogy with the reopening/closing the window. I realized that my original solution wasn't a sliding window now. I modified my code to increment/decrement the left pointer, right pointer, and curVowels count and it passed!  Also great to know that my original solution was actually O(n*k), I see now that my original solution was doing a lot of reprocessing because I keep resetting the pointers. Much appreciated.

Comment: Cheers! You might want to [post this as an answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up fixing my code with the help @Bergi.

The problem with my original answer was that I kept RESETTING the right pointer via `right = left - 1` rather than just "sliding the window" by incrementing the right pointer. My original solution did not work at scale. It was O(n*k) and not O(n) as I originally thought.

And because I kept resetting the right pointer to `right = left - 1`, I was actually doing a lot of re-checking of the same char.

My new solution (that passed) now looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @param {number} k
 * @return {number}
 */
 var maxVowels = function(s, k) {
    let left = 0;
    let right = 0;
    let maxVowels = 0;
    let curVowels = 0;
    let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
    
    while (right < s.length) {
        let subStringLength = right - left + 1;
        if (vowels.includes(s[right])) curVowels++;
        
        if (subStringLength === k) {
            maxVowels = Math.max(maxVowels, curVowels);
            if (vowels.includes(s[left])) curVowels--;
            left++;
        }
        
        right++;
        if (maxVowels === k) return maxVowels;
    }
    return maxVowels;
};
```